# Moneyness for Cancellable Swaps

Tags: swaption, bermudan

Hi I wanted to know we can assess the moneyness of Cancellable swaps?

For example, I have a swap where I am paying the fixed rate and also have an option to cancel this option. How do I assess the moneyness here?

From Bloomberg , Ihave the par coupon rate to be 2.4726% while contract rate is 1.84%

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE. The moneyness of the cancellable swap is the moneyness of the option to cancel, which is basically a swaption in the opposite direction to the swap.

Comment: @byouness If I am paying 1.84% fixed in a swap, in order to cancel I will have to enter into a swap where I will receive 1.84% but the par coupon (swap) rate as of valuation is 2.4726%. Therefore, the option to cancel is OTM right?

Comment: Correct , it is OTM